# Query mongodb date based on client date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

Mongodb stores date object in UTC. I need to query client entered tasks based on "today". Today varies from the user's perspective, who can be in Eastern time zone or Pacific. Here's the issue I ran into:

Record is entered as "2017-05-10 15:15:11.283Z". When I query the server later at night, the server date will be already 2017-05-11, however from the client's perspective it is still 2015-05-10.

I need to find all the tasks client entered "today".

I tried this:

```js
let start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

let end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
```

But while that works during the day (same day), it does not show the records when the client queries at night, but before midnight.

Based on the comments below and my own brainstorming, I now pass client date to the server, and convert to UTC, like this:

```js
let clientDate =  req.params.month +'/'+ req.params.date +'/'+ req.params.year;  //'5/10/2017'
console.log('clientDate ' + clientDate);

let start = new Date(clientDate);
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
start = convertDateToUTC(start);

let end = new Date(clientDate); 
end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);   //need this, otherwise queries next day
end.setHours(0,0,0,0);
end = convertDateToUTC(end);

console.log('start ' + start +' end ' + end);   
            
return Taks.find({goalId: {$in: goalIds}, createdAt: {$gte: start, $lt: end}}).lean() //only today


//using function found on stack overflow
function convertDateToUTC(date) { 
    return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds()); 
}
```

It works correctly, it just seems hacky to supply client date to the server.

Comment: you should pass client timezone and take that into consideration for query

Comment: Are you converting into UTC??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, dates are stored in the database strings with timezone offset +00:00. You want to get Date objects for the start and end of "today" in the client's time zone (whatever that might be).

The following assumes (possibly incorrectly) that the values in *req.params* are UTC, but are being treated as local on the host system doing the processing:

```
let clientDate =  req.params.month +'/'+ req.params.date +'/'+ req.params.year;  //'5/10/2017'
console.log('clientDate ' + clientDate);

let start = new Date(clientDate);
```

That is why your dates are out by the timezone offset and you have to shift them back.

You should not create a string then leave it up to the Date constructor to parse it. Give the values directly to the Date constructor.

Next, you seem to want create a Date for the start and end of the local day that the UTC date falls on, so the following should do that:

```js
var req = {
  params: {
    year: '2017',
    month: '5',
    date: '10'
  }
};

// No parsing, treat date values as UTC
var clientDate = new Date(Date.UTC(req.params.year, req.params.month - 1, req.params.date));

// Copy date
var start = new Date(clientDate);

// Set to local start of day
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

// Copy start to end and add 24 hours
var end = new Date(start);

// Adjusting UTC hours avoids daylight saving issues
// Could also just add 1 to the date
end.setUTCHours(end.getUTCHours() + 24)

console.log('Client date: ' + clientDate.toISOString() +
  '\nstart date : ' + start.toString() +
  '\nend date   : ' + end.toString());
```

For me, being east of Greenwich, the start of 10 May UTC falls on 10 May in my local timezone so I see start and end dates for 10 May. For users west of Greenwich, 10 May starts on 9 May, so they will see start and end dates for 9 May.

I hope that makes sense (and is what you were after).

If, on the other hand, the values in *req.params* are client values, you **must** know the client timezone offset in order to adjust them to the correct date.